# ¿Como simular la entrada por consola en Junit?

Tags: java, junit

Me han mandado realizar pruebas con Junit, el problema es que el programa interactua con el usuario y continuamente da `NullPointerException` en cada una de las pruebas que realizo, ya que **no me permite introducir datos por teclado**.

¿Podríais ayudarme a resolver mi pequeño problema?

El programa es estilo "Akinator" evidentemente por cada pregunta que lanza debo darle una respuesta, el problema es ese, al ejecutar el test simplemente me dan estos errores, no se si debiese controlar otras cosas del Junit, pero en términos de pruebas de este estilo me resulta totalmente imposible la realización de pruebas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**adivinador.java**

```java
package animal;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

// Clase principal: intenta adivinar animales al usuario haciéndole preguntas. Si el usuario
// no acertara, aprende recabando información al propio usuario.
public class Adivinador {

    private Cuestion animales;
    private final String SEPARADOR = " PARA ";

    // Método main.
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Adivinador();
    }

    // Método constructor del adivinador. Incia el árbol cargándolo desde el fichero o, si no existiera, con el coral.
    // A continuación inicia el juego.
    public Adivinador() throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        animales = carga();
        if (animales == null) {
            animales = new Cuestion("coral", null, null);
        }
        String resp="";

        do {
            System.out.println("Piense en un animal...intentaré adivinarlo (pulse intro)");
            resp = br.readLine();

            Desicion d = interroga();
            System.out.println("¿Es el " + animal(d) + "?");
            resp = br.readLine();

            if (resp.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
                System.out.println("¡Soy un genio, acerté!");
            } else {
                aprende(d);
            }

            System.out.println("¿Desea jugar otra vez ?(si/no)");
            resp = br.readLine();

        } while (resp.equalsIgnoreCase("si"));
        guarda();

    }

    // Interroga al usuario con el fin de llegar al nodo donde se almacenan los animales.
    // Para ello va recorriendo el árbol binario hasta llegar a una cuestión que sea un animal.
    public Desicion interroga() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String resp = "";
        Desicion d = new Desicion();

        Cuestion c = animales;
        while (!c.esAnimal()) {
            System.out.println(c.getPregunta());
            resp = br.readLine();
            d.setDesicion(resp, c);
            c = c.getCuestion(resp);
        }
        return d;
    }

    // Método que hace que la aplicación aprenda un animal nuevo. Para ello se le pasa por parámetros
    // la última desición, y le pregunta al usuario que introduzca el animal nuevo y una pregunta afirmativa
    // para ese animal y negativa para el que le ha dicho el programa. A continuación crea una cuestión
    // nueva con ese animal y otra con la pregunta introducida por el usuario, tomando como afirmativa 
    // el animal nuevo y negativa el otro. La cuestión de la pregunta la devuelve como referencia en la
    // misma decisión.
    public void aprende(Desicion d) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        System.out.println("Fallé, ¿que animal era?");
        String animal = br.readLine();
        Cuestion nuevoAnimal = new Cuestion(animal, null, null);
        if (d.esInicial()) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca una pregunta afirmativa para el " + animal + " y negativa para el " + this.animales.getPregunta());
            String preg = br.readLine();
            Cuestion nuevaPregunta = new Cuestion(preg, nuevoAnimal, this.animales);
            this.animales = nuevaPregunta;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Introduzca una pregunta afirmativa para el " + animal + " y negativa para el " + d.getSigCuestion().getPregunta());
            String preg = br.readLine();
            Cuestion nuevaPregunta = new Cuestion(preg, nuevoAnimal, d.getSigCuestion());
            d.getCuestion().setCuestion(nuevaPregunta, d.getRespuesta());
        }
    }

    // Devuelve el animal que corresponde adivinar según la última desición.
    public String animal(Desicion d) {
        if (d.esInicial()) {
            return this.animales.getPregunta();
        } else {
            return d.getSigCuestion().getPregunta();
        }
    }

    // Guarda el árbol de preguntas y animales en un fichero de texto.
    public void guarda() {
        try {
            Cuestion c = animales;
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("./animales.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            guardaArbol(c, pw);
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Guarda todos los nodos que haya por debajo del que se le pasa por paŕametros.
    public void guardaArbol(Cuestion c, PrintWriter pw) {
        if (c == null) {
            pw.println(SEPARADOR);
        } else {
            pw.println(c.getPregunta());
            guardaArbol(c.getCuestion("si"), pw);
            guardaArbol(c.getCuestion("no"), pw);
        }
    }

    // Carga el árbol de preguntas y animales del fichero de texto animales.txt.
    public Cuestion carga() {
        Cuestion c = null;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("./animales.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String pregunta = br.readLine();
            if (pregunta != null) {
                c = new Cuestion(pregunta, null, null);
                cargaArbol(c, br);
            }
            fr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public void cargaArbol(Cuestion c, BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String pregunta = br.readLine();
        if (pregunta != null && !pregunta.equals(SEPARADOR)) {
            Cuestion cs = new Cuestion(pregunta, null, null);
            c.setCuestion(cs, "si");
            cargaArbol(cs, br);
            pregunta = br.readLine();
            if (pregunta != null && !pregunta.equals(SEPARADOR)) {
                Cuestion cn = new Cuestion(pregunta, null, null);
                c.setCuestion(cn, "no");
                cargaArbol(cn, br);
            } else if (pregunta != null) {
                br.readLine();
            }
        } else if (pregunta != null) {
            br.readLine();
        }
    }

}
```

**Cuestion.java**

```
package animal;

// Esta clase representa una cuestión que realiza el adivinador. En función de la respuesta a
// la pregunta lleva a dos posibles cuestiones, una en caso afirmativo y otra en caso negativo.
public class Cuestion extends Object {

    private String pregunta;
    private Cuestion respSi;
    private Cuestion respNo;

    // Método Constructor.
    public Cuestion(String pregunta, Cuestion respSi, Cuestion respNo) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
        this.respSi = respSi;
        this.respNo = respNo;
    }

    // Reescritura del método clone para la asignación de Cuestiones.
    public Object clone(Object o) {
        Cuestion c;
        c = (Cuestion) o;
        return new Cuestion(c.pregunta, c.respSi, c.respNo);
    }

    // Devuelve el texto con la pregunta.
    public String getPregunta() {
        return pregunta;
    }

    // Devuelve la siguiente cuestión en función de si se ha acertado o no la pregunta.
    public Cuestion getCuestion(String resp) {

        if (resp.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
            return respSi;
        } else {
            return respNo;
        }

    }

    // Asigna la siguiente cuestión, indicando la rama, si la afirmativa o la negativa.
    public void setCuestion(Cuestion pCuestion, String resp) {
        if (resp.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
            respSi = pCuestion;
        } else {
            respNo = pCuestion;
        }
    }

    // Devuelve cierto si la cuestión se trata de un animal.
    public boolean esAnimal() {
        if (respSi == null && respNo == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Métodos con fines depurativos.
    public void muestra() {
        System.out.println(this.pregunta);
        if (this.respSi != null) {
            this.respSi.muestra();
        }
        if (this.respNo != null) {
            this.respNo.muestra();
        }
    }
}
```

**Decision.java**

```
package animal;



// Esta clase almacena una desición tomada por el usuario durante el proceso
// de adivinación del animal. La utilidad principal es la de recordar la última
// desición para poder realizar el aprendizaje de un animal nuevo.

public class Desicion {
    private String respuesta;
    private Cuestion cuestion;
    private boolean inicial;

    // Método constructor.
    public Desicion() {
        this.inicial=true;
        this.respuesta="";
        this.cuestion=null;
    }

    // Almacena una determinada desición, respuesta + cuestión planteada.
    public void setDesicion(String respuesta, Cuestion cuestion) {
        this.respuesta=respuesta;
        this.cuestion=cuestion;
        this.inicial=false;
    }

    // Devuelve la respuesta almacenada.
    public String getRespuesta() {
        return this.respuesta;
    }

    // Devuelve la cuestión almacenada.
    public Cuestion getCuestion() {
        return this.cuestion;
    }

    // Devuelve la cuestión correspondiente en función de la respuesta dada por el usuario.
    public Cuestion getSigCuestion() {
        return this.cuestion.getCuestion(respuesta);
    }

    // Devuelve true si no se ha tomado ninguna desición.
    public boolean esInicial() {
        return this.inicial;
    }

    // Método con fines depurativos.
    public void muestra() {
        System.out.println(respuesta);
        cuestion.muestra();
        if (inicial)
            System.out.println("si");
        else
            System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

**AdivinadorTest.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.*/
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import animal.*;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author ordenador
 */
public class AdivinadorTest {

    Adivinador a;
    Cuestion c;

    public AdivinadorTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        a = new Adivinador();
        c = new Cuestion("¿tiene bigotes?", new Cuestion("gato", null, null), new Cuestion("coral", null, null));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        c = null;
    }

    // TODO add test methods here.
    // The methods must be annotated with annotation @Test. For example:
    //
    @Test
    public void pruebaAnimalNo() {
        Desicion d = new Desicion();
        d.setDesicion("no", c);
        String pred = a.animal(d);
        assertTrue(pred.equals("coral"));

    }

    @Test
    public void pruebaAnimalSi() {
        Desicion d = new Desicion();
        d.setDesicion("si", c);
        String pred = a.animal(d);
        assertTrue(pred.equals("gato"));

    }

    @Test
    public void pruebaPrimerAnimal() {
        Desicion d = new Desicion();
        String pred = a.animal(d);

        assertTrue(pred.equals("¿tiene bigotes?"));

    }

    @Test
    public void pruebaCargaCorrecta() {

        assertTrue(a.carga() != null);

    }

    @Test
    public void pruenaGuardadoCorrecto() {
        a.guarda();
        Cuestion cargaPrueba = a.carga();
        assertTrue("¿tiene bigotes?".equals(cargaPrueba.getPregunta()));

    }

    @Test
    public void pruenaClonado() {
        assertTrue(c.clone(c) == c);

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el formato de tu archivo `animales.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

Si te lo permiten puedes usar [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito), una herramienta usada también para pruebas y que funciona simulando otras clases, por lo que puedes declarar objetos *mocks* y definir su comportamiento.
En tu caso para `pruebaAnimalNo()` por ejemplo podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
Decision d = mock(Decision.class);
when(d.esInicial()).thenReturn(true) //o false, según te interese
```

Añadiendo más estructuras `when().thenReturn()` definirías todas las funciones necesarias y luego ejecutarías las pruebas usando el objeto *mock* creado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mejorar el diseño de tu clase Adivinador, inyecta el InputStream por constructor para que desacoples la entrada de datos de tu código, algo así:

```
public Adivinador(InputStream is) throws IOException {
...
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
...
```

Con esto puedes inyectar el inputStream según tu caso de uso, por ejemplo para tus pruebas unitarias podría ser así:

```
@Test
public void pruebaPrimerAnimal() {
 String mockAnswer= "Si\n";
 InputStream is= new ByteArrayInputStream(mockAnswer.getBytes());
 Adivinador a = new Adivinador(is);
 Cuestion c = new Cuestion("¿tiene bigotes?", ...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Desafortunadamente como no nos compartiste tu archivo, solamente puedo darte unos pocos indicios.

A nivel de clase crea una variable de tipo `InputStream`:

```
static InputStream old;
```

Si usas [junit-5](/questions/tagged/junit-5) te recomiendo guardar antes de correr tus pruebas el flujo de entrada estándard antes de correr todas las pruebas unitarias

```
@BeforeAll
public static void setUpClass() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    old=System.in;
}
```

Y regresar al original justo al terminar esta suite de prueba unitarias

```
@AfterAll
public static void tearDownClass() {
    System.setIn(old);
}
```

Ahora para que tu mandes la entrada del teclado vamos a usar una cadena para mandarle al flujo estándard los valores como si los hubiéramos escrito mediante:

```
String inputString = "\r\nsi\r\nsi\r\n";
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Y eso es todo lo que necesitas.
Siempre es bueno que consideres que al correrlo en otro sistema operativo que no sea el tuyo pueden cambiar los terminadores de línea, así que te recomiendo modiicar la cadena en base al sistema opertivo en que corra.