# Pasar un Main a funciones con parámetros JAVA

Tags: java

he hecho un código para un trabajo que al ejecutarlo imprime un histograma con los números que el usuario haya introducido.

Lo que hace es que pide al usuario un número del 0 al 9 hasta que este introduzca un número negativo y cuando lo haga imprime todos los números que ha introducido anteriormente con el signo * encima (según cuantas veces lo haya introducido)

La cosa es que tengo que dividir este programa en funciones con parámetros para poder probarlo en Junit pero siendo un programa que interactúa todo el rato con el usuario no se me ocurre la manera de poder dividirlo en funciones, ¿alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias. El código:

```
package histograma;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    ConsoleInput keyboard = new ConsoleInput(teclado);

    int array[], max = 0, num, i = 0, j = 0;
    boolean salir = false;

    System.out.println("Vamos a crear un Histograma");
    array = new int[100];

    System.out.println("Introduce números del 0 al 9 para ir rellenando el histograma, si introduce un"
            + " número negativo, este terminará\n");

    do {
        for (i = 0; i < array.length && !salir; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un número del 0 al 9 (o un número negativo para imprimir el histograma)");
            num = keyboard.readIntInRangeInclusive(0,9);
            if (num < 0) {
                salir = true;
            }
            else {
                array[num]++;

                if (array[num] > max) {
                    max = array[num];
                }
            }
        }
    } while (!salir);
    for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

            if (array[j] >= max - i && i != max) {
                System.out.print("* ");

            } else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }

            if (j == array.length - 1) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        if (i == max) {
            System.out.print("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Ok, se entiende, pero ese código te funciona así en el main ? No veo donde guardas 
en el array los números que ingresa el usuario por teclado. Por qué incrementas lo que hay en `array[num]`, es decir `array[num]++` ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes extraer partes como la lectura del caracter, condicionales, etc. Por ejemplo:

```
num = keyboard.readIntInRangeInclusive(0,9);
```

puede pasar a:

```
num = Ejercicio.getNumberBetween(0, 9);
```

Implementación:

```
public static int getNumberBetween(int start, intend)
{
    return keyboard.readIntInRangeInclusive(start, end);
}
```

Para los tests unitarios compruebas que te devuelve un número, si es un número dentro del rango, si es un negativo, etc.

Esta pregunta esta relacionada con tu problema: [¿Como simular la entrada por consola en Junit?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266826/como-simular-la-entrada-por-consola-en-junit)