# Como hago una calculadora utilizando 2 archivos con metodos en java

Tags: java, clase, objeto

Necesito crear una calculadora que desde un archivo Principal.java invoque metodos de un archivo Calculadora.java para hacer las operaciones pero siempre me da 0 y no se porque ya trate de todo y no da por favor ayudenme :( les dejo imagenes del codigo aqui.

#### Calculadora.java

[image: Calculadora.java]

#### Principal.java

[image: Principal.java]

### Problema:(

[image: ejecución]

Comment: Agrega tu código aquí por favor

Comment: Sube el código dentro de la pregunta y no como imagenes.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar esta pregunta para darte ideas generales de como cambiarlo de modo main a modo híbrido u modo objeto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355404/pasar-un-main-a-funciones-con-par%c3%a1metros-java

Comment: Gracias a todos por su ayud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en Principal.java, cuando lees los valores, los lees como variables de Principal y la operación de la suma, la haces con valores de Calculadora, tienes 2 opciones:

1. Pásale las variables a Calculadora.

   - Crea un método setter para cada número:

   ```
       public void setNum1(int n){
           this.num1 = n;
       }

       public void setNum2(int n){
           this.num2 = n;
       }
   ```

   - Desde Principal, llama a estos setters con el valor que obtienes:

   ```
       cD.setNum1(num1);
       cD.setNum1(num2);
   ```
2. Cambia el método respuestaSuma para que reciba como parámetro las variables de la suma.

   - Cambia el método:

   ```
       public int respuestaSuma(int n1, int n2){
           return n1 + n2;
       }
   ```

   - Llama al nuevo método desde Principal con los valores que obtienes:

   ```
       total = cD.respuestaSuma(num1,num2);
   ```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, disculpa la tardanza, me sirvio bastante tu ayuda